# Problems with Nightwatch.js and nth-child (css)

Tags: css, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I've got a few of the following elements in my code.

`<img src="/images/myImage.jpg" alt="myImage">`

They are just in the body of the page.
Using `img[src='/images/myImage.jpg']:nth-child(1)` gets the first of those elements. But why can't I use `img[src='/images/myImage.jpg']:nth-child(2)` to locate the second element? 3,4 or 5 aren't working too. Just nth-child(1) is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your full HTML code? My guess is the images are within different parent containers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have other HTML elements mixed with the `<img>` tags you'll need to use `:nth-of-type`. As in:

```
img[src='/images/myImage.jpg']:nth-of-type(2)
```

There's one gotcha though, scroll down past the demo to read more.

**Demo**

```css
img[src='http://placehold.it/200x40']:nth-of-type(3) {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
<div></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
<div></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
<div></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
<div></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
<div></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
<div></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
```

**Note**
Keep in mind `:nth-of-type` and `:nth-child` are psuedo-classes and can only be applied to elements, not attributes or classes. This means `img[src='myImage.jpg']:nth-of-type(4)` will select the 4th `img` element but only if it has a `src` matching `myImage.jpg`. Here's an example.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" alt="test">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" alt="test">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" alt="test">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" alt="test">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" alt="test">

img[src='http://placehold.it/200x20']:nth-of-type(4)
```

This will not result in any style change as the 4th `img` does not have a `src` matching the attribute in the CSS selector. However:

```
img[src='http://placehold.it/200x20']:nth-of-type(5)
```

will apply the style to the 5th `img` since the 5th image's `src` matches the selector.

Comment: Good one, maybe is much better than :nth-child if he have more html elements on the middle :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brett. This sounds quite good. I didn't think of the nth-of-type instead of nth-child. I'll try it with your suggestion tomorrow.
Thanks for the fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using just `img:nth-child(N)`, where N states for a number.